# Почему std::vector<vector<int>> не инициализируется std::initializer_list<initializer_list<int>>

Tags: c++11, vector

При написании класса матрицы решено было использовать следующий подход:

```
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix(int _size) :m_size(_size) {};
    Matrix(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<int>> _input):m_matrix(_input) {};
private:
    int m_size;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> m_matrix;
};
```

Но он не рабочий, т.к. нет подходящего конструктора для вложенного вектора
Какой конструктор можно придумать что бы была возможна инициализация вида:

```
Matrix MyMatrix{{1,2},{3,4}};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте следующий подход:

```
 Matrix(std::initializer_list<std::vector<int>> _input) : m_matrix(_input) {};
```

---

Класс `std::vector` имеет конструктор

```
vector(initializer_list<value_type>, const allocator_type& __a = allocator_type())
```

Соответственно при инстанциировании шаблона имеем следующий конструктор, принимающий список инициализации:

```
vector(initializer_list<vector<int>>, const allocator_type& __a = allocator_type())
```

При этом `initializer_list<vector<int>>` не тождественно `initializer_list<initializer_list<int>>`, поэтому ваш изначальный способ и не работал.

Comment: Ваш вариант отлично работает, осталось только понять разницу. И почему этот шаблон срабатывает.

Answer (score 3):

Можно инициализировать член несколько иным способом, оставив прежнюю сигнатуру конструктора:

```
#include <iterator>
Matrix(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<int>> _input) 
    : m_matrix(std::begin(_input), std::end(_input)) { }
```